# NaN vs floating point exception?

Tags: c++, exception, signals, divide-by-zero

I came across a weird behavior in C++.

Running the following line results in a floating point exception:

```
long double res = 0 / 0 * 100;
```

However, running the following lines results with the variable `res` being printed out as a -nan:

```
long double res = static_cast<long double>(0) / 0 * 100;
std::cout << res << std::endl;
```

Can anyone clarify why this happens? Under what conditions does a calculation evaluate to 'nan' and when will it raise a division by 0 exception as a "floating point exception"?

Comment: Dividing by zero has undefined behavior, so all results are correct.

Comment: The operating system is reporting integer division by 0 as a "floating point exception". This is normal, but very confusing, behavior. And note that the word "exception" here is not a C++ exception; it's an OS "exception", i.e., something went wrong.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting to get an OS exception. I was surprised that I didn't get an OS exception for the floating point zero division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subexpression `0 / 0` is performing integer division since both operands have integer type.  Because there are no NaNs in integer types, this will typically generate a floating point exception.

In contrast, `static_cast<long double>(0) / 0` performs floating point division since one operand has floating point type.  So on implementations that support NaN, this will typically result in NaN on those implementations.

Note that strictly speaking division by zero is undefined behavior, although the above is what you'll most likely experience.

Comment: Clang makes use of the UB and just assumes the expression evaluates to zero. GCC compiles it to an ud2 instruction, which wouldn't cause a floating point exception on the OS level, but a SIGILL instead: https://godbolt.org/z/Yz45aK5Pc

Comment: dbush, Congratulations on 200k